# An efficient way of looping through all files in a directory to process in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, parallel-processing, nlp, with-statement

I have >1million .eml files in a directory that I need to loop through to process. These files contain text that I want to process with a function I have written `text_processing(text)` which takes raw text as input. What I am currently doing is slow and inefficient

```
all_documents = []
for file in files: # files is a list of .eml file names using glob
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        text = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp).get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
        all_documents.append(text_processing(text))
```

The task is embarrassingly parallel (doesnt matter what order the files are processed, and the processing of one file is independent of the processing of all other files), so can be easily parallelised using the Python `multiprocessing` module. However, even when the million files have been distributed among 4 processors, the processing time is still slow.

**Is there some way to optimize the code above to complete the task faster (other than parallelisation) - maybe by replacing the for loop with list comprehension?**

Comment: It's a wild guess, but if parallelising doesn't make a difference, then probably most of the time is spent getting the files from disk (the IO operations). Parallelisation doesn't help you here, because there is only one filesystem. If you need to run this repeatedly, a way to speed it up is packing all files in a `tar` archive, then process them in the order they're stored in the archive. This way, you have only one file access, the rest is sequential reading.